# Jacobian of parametrized ellipsoid with respect to parametrized sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, parametric

I'm not even sure how best to phrase this question, but here goes. Given $\theta$ (elevation) and $\phi$ (azimuth), the unit sphere can be parametrized as

$
x = \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) \\
y = \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
z = \sin(\theta).
$.

A general ellipsoid can then be written as $X = ax$, $Y = by$, $z = cz$.

I'm trying to find the Jacobian that tells you how the sphere was transformed to the ellipsoid. In my mind, this involved computing the following matrix

$
\frac{\partial X}{\partial x},\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial X}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial Y}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial Z}{\partial z}
$

1. Is this correct, or should the "matrix" only have the diagonal entries?
2. If it is not correct, would this idea be correct for an implicit surface?
3. If it is correct, how do I do the differentiation for the off-diagonal entries? Could you work out a single example for differentiating a function with respect to $y$ and $z$?

I've been cracking my head on this one, though it seems like it should be extremely simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $(x,y,z)\mapsto (ax,by,cz) = (X,Y,Z)$ takes three variables to three variables, rather than the two variables of your parametrization. The Jacobian matrix of this three-dimensional transformation is 
$$J = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c \end{bmatrix}.$$
(So the answer to your first question is, "both." The off-diagonal entries are $0$.)

What maybe is confusing you is that this is a three-dimensional transformation and makes no reference to $\theta$ or $\phi$. (Is this why you expect there to be off-diagonal entries?) To see what's going on with the ellipsoid, in particular, you need to find the Jacobian of your parametrization (which tells you how the $\theta$ and $\phi$ directions are distorted by embedding them in three-space) and then compose it with the matrix $J$. This will be equivalent to differentiating the composition $(X(\theta,\phi), Y(\theta,\phi), Z(\theta,\phi))$.

---

Just for kicks, here's another attack that doesn't make any explicit use of calculus. Since the unit sphere is defined implicitly by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, the tangent space to the sphere at the point $p$, is all the vectors perpendicular to $(x,y,z)$. Multiply these vectors by $J$ and you have the vectors to the ellipsoid at $(X,Y,Z)$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Unfortunately, I'm not quite smart enough to understand how to apply this answer to my particular problem. My background is in scientific computing and fluids. Any chance of dumbing this down?

Comment: It's not a matter of smarts! I wrongly guessed that you were a math student taking an upper-level undergraduate class, so I pitched my answer to that background. I'll edit and see if I can make it better.

Comment: @vergere6 I've edited the answer. Does this better answer your question? If not, I'm happy to keep working on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It indeed answers my question. Unfortunately, by not having a math degree at the undergrad level, I seem to have missed out on (or forgotten) some pretty standard stuff. Currently a postdoc in Math after getting a PhD in Scientific Computing.